# Lorentz force transmitted to two nodes

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, satellites

A straight wire of length $L$ and direction $\vec{u}$ carrying a continuous current $I$  in the presence of a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ experiences a force (Lorentz force) equal to $\vec{F} = LI \vec{u} \times \vec{B}$.

If I have represented that wire with two nodes, of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$, connected by a massless spring, how should I distribute that force into those nodes? This is the case of one element of a multipoint model of an electrodynamic tether.

[image]

Thenk you for your help!